# Knockout JS - Delete button not binding correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Hi folks I have a CRUD system I am working on and most of it I got working but for some reason the delete bind dosent seem to work.

This is the error i get in the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unable to parse bindings.
Bindings value: click: delete
Message: Unexpected token }
```

Here is an example of what my site code looks like:

http://jsfiddle.net/rqwku4kb/2/

This is the code thats giving me headaches:

```
Incident.prototype.delete = function(IncidentToRemove) {
    var id = this.ID,
        url = Incident.BASE_URL + (id ? '(' + encodeURIComponent(id) + ')' : '');

    return $.ajax(url, {
        type: 'DELETE',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: ko.toJSON({
            Description: this.Description,
            Incident: this.Incident
        }),
        success: function (data) {
                    console.log("Record was sucessfully saved.");
                    self.incidents.remove(IncidentToRemove);
                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                    }
    });
};
```

I feel like it's something silly but nothing obvious is catching my attention. Would anyone know where the issue might be?

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but from first glance the syntax used to populate the variable `url` looks unusual to me.  Plus does it need a type in front of `url`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `delete` is a reserved keyword, try to use another name. See [JavaScript Reserved Words](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0779sbks(v=vs.94).aspx), but if you really want to use the `delete`
as a function name, you can do that [Reserved words usage in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Reserved_word_usage).

Comment: Well I feel silly now, it worked out. Thank you Joel.